# How to use argmin() and find minimum value from array

Tags: python, numpy, min

I'm new to python so the code may not be the best. I'm trying to find the minimum Total Cost (TotalC) and the corresponding m,k and xM values that go with this minimum cost. I'm not sure how to do this. I have tried using min(TotalC) however this gives an error within the loop or outside the loop only returns the value of TotalC and not the corresponding m, k, and xM values. Any help would be appreciated. This section is at the end of the code, I have included my entire code.

I have tried using

minIndex = TotalC.argmin()

but I'm not sure how to use it and it only returns 0 each time.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def Load(x):
    Fpeak = (1000 + (9*(x**2) - (183*x))) *1000     #Fpeak in N
    td = (20 - ((0.12)*(x**2)) + (4.2*(x))) / 1000  #td in s
    
    return Fpeak, td

#####################################################################################################
####################### Part 2 ########################

def displacement(m,k,x,dt):           #Displacement function

    Fpeak, td = Load(x)               #Load Function from step 1
    
    w = np.sqrt(k/m)                  # Natural circular frequency
    T = 2 * np.pi /w                  #Natural period of blast (s)
    time = np.arange(0,2*T,0.001)     #Time array with range (0 - 2*T) with steps of 2*T/100
    
    
    zt = []                           #Create a lsit to store displacement values
    for t in time:
            if (t <= td):
                zt.append((Fpeak/k) * (1 - np.cos(w*t)) + (Fpeak/(k*td)) * ((np.sin(w*t)/w) - t))
            else:
                zt.append((Fpeak/(k*w*td)) * (np.sin(w*t) - np.sin(w*(t-td))) - ((Fpeak/k) * np.cos(w*t))) 
                
    
    zmax=max(zt)            #Find the max displacement from the list of zt values
    return zmax             #Return max displacement

k = 1E6
m = 200
dt = 0.0001
x = 0


z = displacement(m,k,x,dt)

###################################################################################
############### Part 3 #######################
# k = 1E6 , m = 200kg , Deflection = 0.1m


k_values = np.arange(1E6, 7E6, ((7E6-1E6)/10))   #List of k values between min and max (1E6 and 7E6).
m_values = np.arange(200,1200,((1200-200)/10))   #List of m values between min and max 200kg and 1200kg

xM = []

for k in k_values: # values of k
    for m in m_values: # values of m within k for loop
    

        def bisector(m,k,dpoint,dt):  #dpoint = decimal point accuracy
             xL = 0
             xR = 10
             xM = (xL + xR)/2
             zmax = 99

             while round(zmax, dpoint) !=0.1:
                 zmax = displacement(m,k,xM,dt)
                 if zmax > 0.1:
                     xL = xM
                     xM = (xL + xR)/2
                 else:
                     xR = xM
                     xM = (xL + xR)/2
             return xM

        xM = bisector(m, k, 4, 0.001)
        print('xM value =',xM)
#####################################################
    #######Step 4
        def cost (m,k,xM):
        
            Ck = 900 + 825*((k/1E6)**2) - (1725*(k/1E6))
            Cm = 10*m - 2000
            Cx = 2400*((xM**2)/4)
            TotalC = Ck + Cm + Cx
            minIndex = TotalC.argmin(0)
            print(minIndex)
            return TotalC
    
        TotalC = cost(m, k, xM)
        minIndex = TotalC.argmin()
        print(minIndex)
    
        print([xM, m, k, TotalC])
```

Answer (score 0):

`argmin()` returns the index of a minimum value. If you are looking for the minimum itself, try using `.min()`. There is also a possibility that 0 is the lowest value in your array so bear that in mind.